# Positioning a div/card when hovering over an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have markup as follows:

```js
$('.box').hover(
  function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).addClass('filter');
    $('.card').show();
  },
  function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).removeClass('filter');
    $('.card').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
.card {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  border: thin red solid;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.box {
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
.filter {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.1);
  -moz-filter: opacity(.1);
  -ms-filter: opacity(.1);
  -o-filter: opacity(.1);
  filter: opacity(.1);
}
html,
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <h1 class="text-uppercase">card here</h1>
</div>
```

As can be seen from the snippet, the `.card` element hides as soon as mouse hovers out of the `.box` images. I've also tried using a code like the following:

```
$('.card').removeClass('hidden').delay(2000).queue(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('hidden').dequeue();
  }
);
```

where `.hidden` is provided by Bootstrap. This works, but doesn't achieve what I have in mind.

### Concept

What I'm trying to do here is, the `.card` box will be shown either to the left or right of the `.box` images (depending on the `[data-direction]` attribute), vertically aligned to the middle. The positioning part using JS is not a problem (I think).

### Issue

This card should be visible as long as the mouse is hovering over the `img.box` element, and later, if the mouse leaves the `.box` and the user is trying to select/click on links in the `.card` container, this card should stay visible. Once the user leaves the `.card`, it should fade-out after a small duration.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check out some existing solutions, this is easily doable using CSS only also. [here is one solution](http://usablica.github.io/label.css/#demo)

Sorry I didn't understand correctly on the first time. Checkout my Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ywbz37qp/

```js
var active;

$('.box').hover(
  function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    active = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).addClass('filter');
      var leftOffset = active.parent().position().left;
  console.log(leftOffset);
    $('.card').show().css("left", leftOffset);
  },
  function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).removeClass('filter');
    $('.card').hide();
  }
);

$('.card').hover(
  function(e) {

    $('.card').show();
    $('.box').not(active).addClass('filter');
  },
  function(e) {
    $('.card').hide();
    $('.box').not(active).removeClass('filter');
  }
);
```

```css
.card {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  border: thin red solid;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.box {
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
.filter {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.1);
  -moz-filter: opacity(.1);
  -ms-filter: opacity(.1);
  -o-filter: opacity(.1);
  filter: opacity(.1);
}
html,
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.card{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.wrap{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <h1 class="text-uppercase">card here</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're assuming that the `.card` element appears A. on the image holder, or B. attached to the image, or C. the `.card` contains only text. But neither of those is happening here. The `.card` element will also contain some HTML markup, and maybe a small image/thumbnail with a link to a descriptive page related to a particular image.

Comment: check the edited answer.. basically you need to apply hover class also when hovering the card because the event is not propagated to underlying elemnt

Comment: This is close to what I want to achieve. But, the offset would be calculated as: `var leftOffset = active.parent().position().left + active.parent.width() + 15;`. This will again cause the `.card` to hide itself, when hovering out of the `.box` element.

Comment: the elements need to be connected so you dont left the area, if you want padding add it in the css

Comment: Padding would make the `border` attached to the image, whereas I want a little margin instead.

Comment: use margin then instead of padding.. I've done and explained it all to you and you didn't even accept my answer..

Comment: Using a margin causes the same error [as before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209256/positioning-a-div-card-when-hovering-over-an-image/37209335?noredirect=1#comment61951952_37209335) i.e. the `.card` hides itself when hovering out of `.box`. But, your answer combined with [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215358/1190388) gave me an idea. I'm still playing around with the code. Will publish it if I get it to work properly.

Comment: oh okay.. then just use another wrapper so that the .card is touching the .box and inside of the .card make .cardContent or whatever that will have a border.. that way you can freely use the padding this is really basic css and has nothing to do with the original question that I answered correctly but you have to put some effort in that too

Answer (score 1):

Is the below what you're trying to achieve?

```js
$('.box').hover(
  function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).addClass('filter');
    $('.card').show();
    $('.card').hover("", function(){$('.card').hide();})
  }, function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.box').not($this).removeClass('filter');
  }
);
```

```css
.card {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  border: thin red solid;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.box {
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
.filter {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.1);
  -moz-filter: opacity(.1);
  -ms-filter: opacity(.1);
  -o-filter: opacity(.1);
  filter: opacity(.1);
}
html,
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
    <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <h1 class="text-uppercase">card here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your idea of nesting another `.hover` listener suggests me something else. I'll try to refine it a little in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Just alter your javascript like in the below example

```js
$('.box').addClass('filter'); // apply filter class to all box elements
$('.box').on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('filter');
    $('.card').show(300).offset({ top: 100, left: $(this).offset().left});
});
$('.box').on('mouseout',function() {
    $(this).addClass('filter');
    $('.card').hide(950);
});
```

```css
.card {
          display: none;
          width: 100px;
          height: auto;
          border: thin red solid;
          border-radius: 2em;
          padding: 1em 0;
          position:fixed;
          top:100px;
        }
        .box {
          transition: all .5s linear;
          height:300px;
        }
        .filter {
          -webkit-filter: opacity(.1);
          -moz-filter: opacity(.1);
          -ms-filter: opacity(.1);
          -o-filter: opacity(.1);
          filter: opacity(.1);
        }
        html,
        body {
          background-color: aquamarine;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
            <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
            <img class="box" data-direction="right" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
            <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-xs-3">
            <img class="box" data-direction="left" src="https://placehold.it/100x300" />
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase">card here</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is not at all what my question states, or what is desired.